Citus Colocation Behavior
I am using Citus as a managed service in the cloud with Azure Cosmos DB for PostgreSQL.
I have 1 coordinator and 2 worker nodes setup.
There are distributed tables and reference tables created.
Distributed tables are horizontally partitioned across all nodes.
A reference table is a table whose entire contents are concentrated into a single shard which is replicated on every worker.
For each distributed table, about 30 shards were created.
3 shards were created for each reference table given that there are 3 nodes in total.
Citus Shards Query
Upon executing the above query to get all shards, I see that the shards of the distributed tables are spread across all nodes by looking at the nodename column.
Also for reference tables, I see all shards are duplicated across all nodes.
However, I noticed that the colocation ID of all reference table shards is the same (say 23).
And the colocation ID of all distributed table shards is the same (say 26).
This does not make sense to me given that the shards of distributed and reference tables are present in all nodes.
This is how the output looks like:
Query Output
Can anyone explain the behavior of this?

The query output seems logical to me. Let me explain some of the Citus concepts so that you understand what is going on.
Concepts
Shard: a table that contains a portion of the data for a PostgreSQL table. A distributed table has 32 shards by default, whereas a reference table has a single shard always.
Shard placement: each occurence of a shard in a node. For example, in your cluster your reference table has 3 placements as all the nodes contain a copy of the single shard associated with the table.
Colocation: a logical grouping of distributed tables so that all the joins on distribution columns can be executed without copying data across nodes.
Explanation
If you decide to change the shard count of a distributed table, Citus changes the shard count of all the tables in the same colocation so that the joins still happen in the same nodes. Having the same colocation id implies that the shards for the same distribution column value reside in the same nodes.
You can have a high number of colocations in your cluster. Although all the tables in different colocation groups can be locally joined in the workers, they all have a different colocation group than the ones for reference tables.
